# Postgresql:exporting data from local database to remote server in csv

Tags: postgresql, psql

I want to send data from my local postgresql to a remote server in csv form..
something similar to 
`copy (select * from table) to /home/ubuntu/a.csv with csv` 
But in place of local direcory, I want to take this csv dump in other server

Comment: Is not supported by `COPY` but there is some workarounds. Describe better you scenario. Are you using psql? Take a look here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36235/export-postgres-table-on-remote-server-to-csv-file-on-local-machine

Answer (score 0):

Use the `psql` client's `\copy` feature; this does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know copy command reads/writes from local path/location. To generate the output file on the remote server, you need to use a script(bash/python) to execute copy command on remote server.

Comment: `copy` always writes the file on the **server**. Don't confuse it with psql's `\copy` which writes the file to the client.